# Error Code: 1111 Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I have this query

```
SELECT perf_prog.date, MAX(perf_prog.end_time) , ADDTIME((shift_time.out), "01:00:00") FROM perf_prog 
INNER JOIN Shifts ON perf_prog.emp_id = Shifts.emp_id 
INNER JOIN shift_time ON Shifts.id = shift_time.id

WHERE perf_prog.emp_id = 920   GROUP BY perf_prog.date
```

and this is the output of the query

[image]

But i want to list only those value of end_time which is greater than shift_time.out

so i did this

```
SELECT perf_prog.date, MAX(perf_prog.end_time) , ADDTIME((shift_time.out), "01:00:00") FROM perf_prog 
INNER JOIN Shifts ON perf_prog.emp_id = Shifts.emp_id 
INNER JOIN shift_time ON Shifts.id = shift_time.id

WHERE perf_prog.emp_id = 920 AND MAX(perf_prog.end_time) > ADDTIME((shift_time.out), "01:00:00")   GROUP BY perf_prog.date
```

but i'm receiving error

```
Error Code: 1111
Invalid use of group function
```

and upon searching stackoverflow the answer that solved their problem is move the condition to having clause

so i got this

```
SELECT perf_prog.date, MAX(perf_prog.end_time) , ADDTIME((shift_time.out), "01:00:00") FROM perf_prog 
INNER JOIN Shifts ON perf_prog.emp_id = Shifts.emp_id 
INNER JOIN shift_time ON Shifts.id = shift_time.id

WHERE perf_prog.emp_id = 920 GROUP BY perf_prog.date  
HAVING MAX(perf_prog.end_time)   > ADDTIME((shift_time.out), "01:00:00")
```

and now the problem is `Unknown column 'shift_time.out' in 'having clause'`

Am i following the correct solution for my needs? Thank you. ive been trying to figure out the solution but i can't make it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an aggregation on the column.  I think this might be what you want:

```
SELECT pp.date, MAX(pp.end_time),
       MAX(ADDTIME((st.out), '01:00:00'))
FROM perf_prog pp INNER JOIN
     Shifts s
     ON pp.emp_id = s.emp_id INNER JOIN
     shift_time st
     ON s.id = st.id
WHERE pp.emp_id = 920
GROUP BY pp.date  
HAVING MAX(pp.end_time) > MAX(ADDTIME((st.out), '01:00:00))
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. That solve my problem